# Show custom tab only for specific attribut set

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel

I have custom tab in product page admin panel. I want to show that tab only if product attribute set is equals to "Frame" in both add product and edit product page. I have tried with xml but its not working

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_9>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>my_custom_edittab</name>
            <block>customtabs/adminhtml_catalog_product_edittab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
    </PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_9>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>

<adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
    <PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_9>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>my_custom_tab</name>
            <block>customtabs/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
    </PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_9>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add the attribute set condition in there.
However, you can achieve what you are looking for by extending the Tabs core class for product adminhtml form.

To do that, copy `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php` and inside the `_prepareLayout()` method you can check the attribute set id, and add the tab.

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $product = $this->getProduct();

    if (!($setId = $product->getAttributeSetId())) {
        $setId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('set', null);
    }

    if($setId == MY_SET_ID) {
        $this->addTab('productalert', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('My Custom Tab'),
             'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customtabs/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab', 'my.custom.tab')->toHtml()
        ));
    }
    [...]
```